# Access data at memory address with ctypes

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I am trying to create a Python wrapper for an old C program that takes inputs as pointers.  At this point, I can get the program to run but cannot figure out how to get back the values at the designated pointers.

This is a simplified C script:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void cprogram(double *wts, double *res, int *kks, int n, double *ex) {
  int m;
  m=n+1;
  res[0]=1.0;
  kks[0]=1.0;}
```

And this is my simplified Python code:

```
from ctypes import *
import sys

libc = CDLL("src/program.so")  

class CONTEXT(Structure):
  _fields_ = [
                ("wts", POINTER(c_double)), //tried just to see if it would work
                ("res", c_double),
                ("kks", c_int),
                ("n", c_int),
                ("ex", c_double)]

def runner():
    kk = (1,2,3)
    n = 3
    mm = n + 1
    wts = (c_double * n)(1, 1, 1)
    res = (c_double * mm)(0)
    kks = (c_int * len(kk))(*kk)
    n = c_int(n)
    ex = c_double(0)

    libc.cprogram.restype = POINTER(CONTEXT)

    tmp = libc.cprogram(wts, res, kks, n, ex)

runner()
```

I have tried commands like `print tmp[1].wts[1]` and `print tmp[2]` but this only prints the memory address and not the value (or incredibly small values that are incorrect like 2.15880221124e-314).  I would like to be able to return a list of the values of wts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C function returns `void`, not a `CONTEXT *`. So, your code is just casting random uninitialized memory to a `CONTEXT *`, and then trying to deref it.

On top of that, even if it *did* return a `CONTEXT` object by reference, `tmp[1]` would try to deref the memory *after* that object, so it would *still* be garbage.

When you try to interpret random memory as a double, you're going to get segfaults or values like `2.15880221124e-314` if you're lucky—if you're unlucky, you'll get correct-looking but still random values like `0.0`.

---

Meanwhile, since your C function modifies its arguments in place, you don't need to do anything fancy here. Just use the variables you passed in.

So:

```
def runner():
    kk = (1,2,3)
    n = 3
    mm = n + 1
    wts = (c_double * n)(1, 1, 1)
    res = (c_double * mm)(0)
    kks = (c_int * len(kk))(*kk)
    n = c_int(n)
    ex = c_double(0)

    libc.cprogram.restype = None

    libc.cprogram(wts, res, kks, n, ex)

    print wts[1]
```

This works, and prints out `1.0`.

---

And if your C function *did* return an array of `CONTEXT` structs matching your `ctypes` declaration, this would all work fine. For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
  double *wts;
  double res;
  int kks;
  int n;
  double ex;
} CONTEXT;

CONTEXT *cprogram(double *wts, double *res, int *kks, int n, double *ex) {
  int m;
  m=n+1;
  res[0]=1.0;
  kks[0]=1.0;

  CONTEXT *contexts = malloc(sizeof(CONTEXT) * 4);
  for (int i=0; i!=4; ++i) {
    double *wtsses = malloc(sizeof(double) * 5);
    for (int j=0; j!=4; ++j) {
      wtsses[j] = i + j;
    }
    CONTEXT context = { wtsses, *res, *kks, m, *ex };
    contexts[i] = context;
  }
  return contexts;
}
```

Compile this, run your existing Python script with an added `print tmp[1].wts[1]`, and it will print out `2.0`.

---

Finally, for your followup, first let's change the C code to take `int *n`, where `*n` is the input:

```
void cprogram(double *wts, double *res, int *kks, int *n, double *ex) {
  int m;
  m=*n+1;
  res[0]=1.0;
  kks[0]=1.0;}
```

Now, to call this from Python, you have to create a `c_int` and pass a pointer to it. Since you're already doing the first half (which wasn't necessary before—just set `argtypes` instead… but it's necessary now, which is convenient), it's just a one-line change:

```
libc.cprogram(wts, res, kks, pointer(n), ex)
```

This even works if `n` is an in-out parameter.

---

But really, you don't need to see the pointer object at all from the Python; the only thing you're doing with it is creating it to pass to the function, then letting it get collected. To pass a C pointer without creating a ctypes pointer object (which again works even if `n` is an in-out parameter), use `byref`:

```
libc.cprogram(wts, res, kks, byref(n), ex)
```

Comment: Thank you for putting in the time and effort to explain and fix my errors!  The only thing I found was that `c_void` doesn't seem to exist but `None` worked in its place.  I don't know very much C so I am trying to avoid altering that code.

Comment: Quick followup: How would I go about making it so the C function took n in as a pointer `*n` and then operated on it by doing `m=*n+1`?  My current code fails.  Specifically, is there a quick fix in the Python code to do this?

Comment: @brebs: Right, sorry, `void *` is `c_void_p`, but `void` is just `None`. Anyway, for the followup, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @eryksun: I thought it would be easier to explain without that change, since the OP is specifically asking how to make a pointer… but you're right, it's probably better to explain why he doesn't really want to make a pointer (that he can access from Python/ctypes) in the first place. I'll edit the answer.